# Calling a Method in java depending on a given string

Tags: java, methods, call

I want to call a method in java with a given string like this for example:

```
String string = "HelloWorld";
main.string();
```

I want something like this to call the method defined in the string, would that be possible? If not (which I am kind of expecting), are there alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main possibilities:

- you know wich methods can be called from a particular string
- you don't know wich methods can be called

If you know wich methods can be called you only need to do something like

```
switch(str) {
    case "first":
        obj.firstMethod();
        break;
    case "second":
        obj.secondMethod();
        break;
}
```

if you don't know wich methods can be called and the string represent the name of the method you can use the reflection as other already commented